# Sudoers - Execute command without sudo command

Tags: command-line, sudo

I have this rule in my sudoers file

```
user ALL = (root) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/supervisorctl
```

Now I can run the command without root password.

For example :

```
sudo supervisorctl restart all
```

My question is How can I run the command without sudo command ?

```
supervisorctl restart all
```

Comment: When you want to run it without typing `sudo ` in front, you could define an alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can set the `setuid` bit to have an executable run as the owner of the file, not as the user who starts the command. This approach can have serious security implications, though. So is, of course, also the removal of a password to run sudo.

Easier and much safer in your current situation is to create an alias:

```
alias supervisorctl='sudo supervisorctl'
```

after which `supervisorctl` will automatically be interpreted as `sudo supervisorct`